# Favicons looking weird in address bar suggestions

Tags: bug, design, favicon

Site favicons are blurry and look smaller in address bar autocomplete suggestions. Picture worth a thousand words:

[image]

I'm using the latest Firefox Developer Edition, but I've been seeing this for maybe more than half a year.

I just made a test page to see who's crazy and turns out it works fine with the old favicon which I've got saved a long time ago and it only has 16px version:

[image]

And then I tested it with the new favicon (has both 16px and 32px sizes) I got from the site just now, and it's as bad as you can see:

[image]

To see if it's a Firefox issue or the icon format issue, I resaved the new favicon using Gimp and there were multiple available combinations of options. I chose the default settings first and the results were bad:

[image]

Then I selected matching settings for both sizes and the favicon looked… bad again?

[image]

Lastly I tried enabling the compression, even though it isn't the most compatible option, but it worked fine:

[image]

Not sure what that means but perhaps some compatibility settings can be flipped around until favicons look good on all browsers.

Comment: It sounds like it may just be a browser issue? A favicon's a favicon. They're the correct size/clarity on the site, but I'm sure there's ways to screw up the display in other contexts.

Comment: Well, as you can see, it looks just right on the tabs themselves. I don't know if Firefox is rendering them badly in the suggestions because of how they're implemented here (a sprite sheet) but it might be worth looking into, as I don't see that problem with any other sites on the internet.

Comment: @AdamLear I ran some tests and updated the post.